# First two letters missing in file transfer in java

Tags: java, client-server, file-transfer

I am working on a client/server transfer protocol in java. The client is sending a simple text file, everything is going across the wire fine in wireshark, but once it gets to the server side, the first two letters are missing from the text file. I believe that it is overwriting the first buffer for some reason.

My goal is to make a while loop that reads the bytes in the buffer and then increments a count that'll place the next set of bytes....in the place if the ones already written

Here is the server's code that I currently have:

```
                                int bytesRead;
                                int current = 0;
                                InputStream in = s.getInputStream();

                                // Instantiating a new output stream object
                                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(myFile); 
                                PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(output);

                                // Receive file 1024 bytes at a time
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) { 
                                    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                    System.out.println(output.toString());
                                }
```

Comment: `PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(output);` - what is this used for?

Comment: `System.out.println(output.toString());` what do you think that does?

Comment: sorry, System.out.println.. was for debugging

Comment: @DevanJ - then why not try to print the `buffer` ?

Comment: Check md5 of file to see if the file is being transferred from client to serve correctly.

Comment: @ScaryWombat when I print the buffer, I get an 11 digit hash number...I'm assuming the md5? Printing the it on the client side is giving me a different number...

Comment: No you probably need to convert the byte array to a String first `new String(buffer)`

Comment: @ScaryWombat got it. And it is still missing the first two letters when printed

Comment: Maybe it is the fault of the client?

Comment: I'll check, but going across the wire, the file does have the first two letters after it leaves the client